# Can I modify a question significantly to make it less broad?

Tags: discussion

In an effort to reopen the ["T" question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60126/4729), I've written a riddle which narrows the number of suitable answers, and retains the original intended answer. Is it too much for me to essentially re-write the question just to make it fit? Should I just abandon it unless the OP edits?

My intended edit does away with all of the original text and replaces it with:

> I don a coat to keep me warm,
>  I'm squat and round, that is my form.
>  I start with T,
>  I end with T,
>  My inside is filled up with T,
>  You get your kicks and calms from me,
>  Can you deduce what must I be?

Comment: Well that's a nice poem. Iambic tetrameter?

Comment: I didn’t aim for a specific meter. I just made it sound “right”

Comment: It sounds right to me, I like it. If you read *I start with T, I end with T* as one line, the whole thing fits nicely in iambic tetrameter.

Comment: +1 simply for the clever riddle, but ultimately I agree with Rand al'Thor's answer. IMO you should leave it for another time, and post it in a few month's time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I think this is definitely too much for *you* to change the question.** If someone with less than 2k rep suggested this as an edit, I'd reject it under "*clearly conflicts with author's intent*". That's far too drastic a change to make without the OP's permission.

In fact, it might possibly be too big an edit for even the OP themselves to make! Although it would make the question reopenable, it would also invalidate many of the existing answers, which isn't really fair to those who've taken the time to answer and even earned reputation for it. I'm not sure about this though, as puzzle-narrowing edits which invalidate existing answers do happen on this site, and quite often the invalidated answers aren't even deleted. It's one of those ways in which Puzzling operates differently from the rest of the SE sites.

(The fact that you're the accepted answerer would also make it look very bad if you were to make this edit. You'd essentially be changing the question so that *your* answer fits but other people's answers don't. I realise your intentions are good here, but it would be very easy for people to accuse you of abuse if you did this.)

**What you've written here is essentially a different puzzle with the same solution.** It might even be postable as a new question. There's nothing wrong with having multiple different riddles cluing the same solution in different ways; in fact, it's common for one puzzle to inspire someone, e.g. someone who failed to solve it, to post another broadly similar puzzle themselves. (Of course, now that people on meta have seen your puzzle and its solution, it makes less sense to post it on the main site. A lesson for another time, perhaps.)